# Properly frame CALayers over a video swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, calayer

I have an app where you can move images and text on a video kinda like Snapchat and Instagram stories. I use AVMutableVideoComposition to add the images and text to the video as CALayers. But when I save the video, the position and size of the images and texts in the saved video are completely off. I made some research and found out that I need to calculate the scale of the video frame to that of the view's frame and multiply the x, y, width and height values of the layers by that scale but it's still not working

```
let size = videoTrack.naturalSize.applying(videoTrack.preferredTransform)
let scale: CGFloat = (size.width) / (self.view.frame.size.width)
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.contents = image.image?.cgImage
imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: (image.frame.origin.x) * scale, y: (image.frame.origin.y) * scale, width: (image.frame.size.width) * scale, height(image.frame.size.height) * scale)
```

Comment: Life is not that simple.  You have to figure out the current position of a layer based on the original video size, also taking into consideration the letter box size.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do. Do you have any idea that could help me do that ?

Comment: If don't, I wouldn't have made a comment.  It's tool complicated to explain how you do it.